# Pagamento com Cartão de Crédito

Tags: android

Tem como fazer um sistema de pagamento via **[cartão de crédito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cart%C3%A3o_de_cr%C3%A9dito)**, mas sem usar `PayPal`, `PagSeguro`, `PagamentoDigital` ou Outros?

As Empresas dos Cartões disponibilizam algum tipo de *Código*, *[API](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)*, ou *SDK*?

Comment: Sim mas ai existem questões contratuais a serem acordadas  com o banco do cliente que vai usar o sistema e receber pagamentos em sua conta sem intermediários.

Comment: Sim, existem empresas como a Redecard e a Cielo que fazem isso e possuem API própria.